# Dynamically create 2D text in three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I have 3D model which I have created in three.js. Based on some data, I want to create a set of arrows which is decorated by a small text label. These labels should be in 2D.

It seems like I have two alternatives: either use a separate canvas element to create a texture which in its turn is used in the 3D model, or use HTML on top the 3D model's canvas element.

I'm wondering how to go about this. Which is the "correct" way to do this? Any suggestions and example code is very welcome!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you don't mind that the text will always be on top (e.g. if the object is blocked by something else, its text label will still be visible and on top of everything else), and that the text will not be affected by any rendering like lights/shadow, etc, then HTML is the easiest way to go imho.

Here is some sample code:

```
var text2 = document.createElement('div');
text2.style.position = 'absolute';
//text2.style.zIndex = 1;    // if you still don't see the label, try uncommenting this
text2.style.width = 100;
text2.style.height = 100;
text2.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
text2.innerHTML = "hi there!";
text2.style.top = 200 + 'px';
text2.style.left = 200 + 'px';
document.body.appendChild(text2);
```

Substitute 200 in the style.top and style.left variables for the y and x coordinates (respectively) you wish to place the text.  They will be positive values where (0,0) is the top left of the canvas.  For some guidance on how to project from the 3D point in your canvas to a 2D point in pixels in your browser window, use a code snippet like the following:

```
function toXYCoords (pos) {
        var vector = projector.projectVector(pos.clone(), camera);
        vector.x = (vector.x + 1)/2 * window.innerWidth;
        vector.y = -(vector.y - 1)/2 * window.innerHeight;
        return vector;
}
```

Make sure you have called camera.updateMatrixWorld() beforehand.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had some issues projecting the coordinates myself, but it turned out I forgot to do a camera.updateMatrixWorld() before projecting the vector. The result was unusable values way off the screen.

Comment: Hey thanks for this answer, I tried it in Three r79 and it returns this error `projector is not defined`, is there a workaround this ? thanks

Comment: When I move the objects or rotate the camera, I have to update the text position manually (?) Is there some way how to make this update automatic? For example If I want to make 2D labels on top of each object in scene while everything is moving.

Comment: Prokop Hapala-- it sounds like your best bet is to make the labels a part of the 3D scene; see the solution from @LeeStemkoski below

Comment: @kronuus Hi could you take a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61631545/add-text-with-geometry-in-threejs

Comment: [CSS2DRenderer](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/renderers/CSS2DRenderer) is the current implementation of this approach and it automates the positioning for you.

Answer (score 25):

Check out the  [**demo**](https://seregpie.github.io/aframe-text-sprite/).

`TextGeometry` consumes a lot of memory and you need to load a font, which contains a geometry for each letter, you will be using. If I have more than 100 text meshes in a scene, my browser crashes.

You can draw text on a canvas and include it in your scene via a `Sprite`. The problem with it is that you need to calculate the font size. If you have a moving camera, then you need to calculate the font size periodically. Otherwise the text will get to blurry, if you get too close to the text with the camera.

I wrote a class [TextSprite](https://github.com/SeregPie/THREE.TextSprite) which automatically calculates the best possible font size, depending on the distance to the camera and the size of the renderer element. The trick is to use the callback `.onBeforeRender` of the class [Object3D](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/Object3D), which receives the camera and the renderer.

```js
let sprite = new THREE.TextSprite({
  text: 'Hello World!',
  fontFamily: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
  fontSize: 12,
  color: '#ffbbff',
});
scene.add(sprite);
```

You can also change the text and the font on the fly.

```js
sprite.text = 'Hello Stack Overflow!';
sprite.fontFamily = 'Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif';
sprite.fontSize = 24;
```

Comment: huh. Instead of doing this, I used method of projecting from the camera to find the position of an html element that I then positioned with absolute positioning. I kind of wish I had used this, though. Good job! :D

Comment: Want to mention that this solution is not amazing if you are rendering hundreds of TextSprites. Performance is effected

Comment: @SeregPie Hi could you please have a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61631545/add-text-with-geometry-in-threejs

Comment: Tried the demo but nothing visible on screen (Firefox 83, 32bit).

Comment: @steveOw Oh, thanks. I fixed it now. There was a AFrame update and unpkg could not resolve the package.

Answer (score 20):

If you actually want to include text (or any image) from a canvas object as part of your 3D scene, check out the sample code at:
http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Texture-From-Canvas.html

Comment: I used your example when figuring it out for the first time :) Thanks a lot for great tutorials! I am wondering though, why is it that using the canvas method results in blurry text (at least its rendered like that on my machine)?

Comment: Perhaps it is an artifact of antialiasing?

Comment: Also I believe this uses some functions no longer included in Three.js

Comment: The blurry text seems to happen (mainly) because three.js renders the sprite as square even though the canvas is probably wider than it is high.  If you scale the sprite to have the same proportions as the canvas, it should look better.

Answer (score 10):

**Update** : This method is Deprecated now and is CPU heavy, don't use it.

I found out another only three.js based solution,

```
var textShapes = THREE.FontUtils.generateShapes( text, options );
var text = new THREE.ShapeGeometry( textShapes );
var textMesh = new THREE.Mesh( text, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } ) ) ;
scene.add(textMesh);
// Example text options : {'font' : 'helvetiker','weight' : 'normal', 'style' : 'normal','size' : 100,'curveSegments' : 300};
```

Now to edit this text dynamically,

```
var textShapes = THREE.FontUtils.generateShapes( text, options );
var text = new THREE.ShapeGeometry( textShapes );
textMesh.geometry = text;
textMesh.geometry.needsUpdate = true;
```

Comment: It should be noted though that this is a very expensive method to adopt for creating 2D text.  Using HTML in the canvas is more sensible if you're thinking of displaying standard 2D text.

Comment: You are using text before define it. Please, check the vars names.

Comment: I think that's now deprecated in favour of [TextShape](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Geometries/TextGeometry)

Answer (score 8):

I've published a module on NPM that does that for you: https://github.com/gamestdio/three-text2d

It allows you to have an `Sprite` or `Mesh` with the rendered text without dealing with canvas manually.

**Example:**

```
var Text2D = require('three-text2d').Text2D

var text = new Text2D("Hello world!", { font: '30px Arial', fillStyle: '#000000', antialias: true })
scene.add(text)
```

Comment: Could you give examples on how to use your module? I'm just beginning to use ThreeJS, so I only have the ThreeJS hello-world example up. I believe I can't require('three-text2d') inside it, so should I use a package like browserify to compile your package with ThreeJS?  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can create a 2d canvas and use css to position it to the top of your webgl canvas. Then you can draw text on it using the `ctx.fillText(text,x,y)` or `ctx.strokeText(text,x,y)` methods provided by the 2d canvas context. By using this method you can draw other things besides text, such as arrows and meters.

You can use the method as suggested by @kronuus to convert a point from 3d to 2d space.

Comment: Is this more performing than HTML elements positioned on top of my threejs canvas?

Answer (score 3):

The response by @LeeStemkoski was quite useful. Yet there is a slight change that needs to be done to the code **in order for the text to follow your arrows around** i.e. in case the arrow gets moved around, rotated, etc.

See the next code

```js
var canvas1 = document.createElement('canvas');
var context1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
context1.font = "Bold 10px Arial";
context1.fillStyle = "rgba(255,0,0,1)";
context1.fillText('Hello, world!', 0, 60);

// canvas contents will be used for a texture
var texture1 = new THREE.Texture(canvas1)
texture1.needsUpdate = true;

var material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: texture1,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
});
material1.transparent = true;

var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.PlaneGeometry(50, 10),
    material1
);
mesh1.position.set(25, 5, -5);
mesh1.rotation.x = -0.9;
shape.add(mesh1);
// Note that mesh1 gets added to the shape and not to the scene

scene.add(shape)
```

As you can see, the trick is to add the text (`mesh1`) **to the `shape`** (your "arrow") **instead of adding it to the scene**.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

From the "geometry / text / shape" of Three js :
https://threejs.org/examples/?q=text#webgl_geometry_text_shapes

I simplified the code for just have the strict necessary to add a 2D dynamic text :

```
var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
loader.load( 'assets/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json', function ( font ) {   
    var textPositions = [[1, 1, 1],
                         [2, 2, 2]];

    var textMessages = ['Text 1', 'Text 2'];

    var textSizes = [0.1, 0.2];

    var textName = ['text1', 'text2'];

    var textsNumber = textPositions.length;     

    for (var i = 0; i < textsNumber; i++) {
```

> the method 'generateShapes' permit to create the text in shape

```
        var textsShapes = font.generateShapes( textMessages[i], textSizes[i] );
        var textsGeometry = new THREE.ShapeBufferGeometry( textsShapes );    
        var textsMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xeeeeee});

        var text = new THREE.Mesh(textsGeometry, textsMaterial);
        text.position.set(textPositions[i][0], textPositions[i][1], textPositions[i][2]);
        text.name = textName[i]; 

        scene.add(text);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the current Version of three.js (r160) there is an addon [CSS2DRenderer](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/renderers/CSS2DRenderer). With this you can create a second renderer on top of the `WebGLRenderer` and draw any HTML-objects in it, which are then updated from the position of the object in the `WebGLRenderer`.

Based on [this](https://threejs.org/examples/#css2d_label) example:

imports:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { CSS2DRenderer, CSS2DObject } from 'three/addons/renderers/CSS2DRenderer.js';
```

create both renderers:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

labelRenderer = new CSS2DRenderer();
labelRenderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
labelRenderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
labelRenderer.domElement.style.top = '0px';
document.body.appendChild( labelRenderer.domElement );
```

create the 3D-Element:

```
const axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper( 5 );
scene.add( axesHelper );
```

create a `CSS2DObject` and connect it with the position of the 3D-Element:

```
const axesDiv = document.createElement( 'div' );
axesDiv.className = 'label';
axesDiv.textContent = 'My Axis';
axesDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';

const axisLabel = new CSS2DObject(axesDiv);
axisLabel.position.set(0, 0, 0 );
axisLabel.center.set( 0, 0 );

// connect by adding to 3D-Element
axesHelper.add( axisLabel );
```

and last, but not least the animation loop containing both renderers:

```
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
  labelRenderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Now, if you change the position of your 3D-object or your camera, the position of the Div-Element in your HTML-document will be updated by using a CSS-Translation.