# Text overlays in Three.js disrupt dragging

Tags: javascript, three.js

Following the suggestions on Github (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1321) and here on Stakoverflow ([Dynamically create 2D text in three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248872/dynamically-create-2d-text-in-three-js)), I opted to overlay text within HTML divs.

The issue I'm having is when the user is rotating the scene and the cursor passes over any of the divs,  dragging stops. The drag action does not resume when the cursor continues on the other side of the text div. This results in the drag action mysteriously stopping and can only be resumed by releasing the mouse button and reapplying.

The example I'm talking about is on this page: http://www.intmath.com/vectors/3d-space-interactive-applet.php

I'm using stock standard OrbitControls.js with  `controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);`

I've tried:

(1) Detecting `mouseout` from the div and setting `controls.enabled true` didn't work. Also toggling `controls.enabled = false` certainly disabled the controls, but I couldn't get them to fire up again on `mouseout`.

(2) Simulating a `mouseup` (while over the div) then `mousedown` on `mouseout` from the div - also gave no luck.

(3) Trying to hide the div on `mouseover`, but of course it's too late by then - the drag motion has already stopped.

(4) Disabling highlighting of the text in the divs - no change

So is it possible to reactivate the dragging motion after dragging over a div, and if so, how?

Regards

Comment: It's tough to say since you don't have any information about your setup. OrbitControls.js, for example, uses document level mouse listeners (see line 703 in three.js/examples/js/controls). So firing a mouseout event would require mousing out of the document, such as if your 3d canvas were sitting in an iframe. As well, the controls classes in the examples folder are not part of the Three.js build and can be safely modified. Remove the mouseout declaration in the controls class your using. It's probably firing the same event as its mouseup event anyways and can be safely removed.

Comment: @Radio: I edited my question to make the example code more clear. Your suggestion of removing the mouseout declaration near line 703 did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: Saw it @ http://www.intmath.com/vectors/3d-space-interactive-applet.php Looks awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Set the CSS rule `pointer-events: none` on the labels.

Comment: Changing the `pointer-events` rule didn't change the behavior I was trying to fix, but it did help the UI. Thanks a lot.

Comment: this fixed my problem. THANKS!